# Why i get this error while saving a product custom attribute value?

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I am trying to save product values with these simple code to test.

```php
 $p = Mage::getModel("catalog/product");
       $p->setData("sku","real val sku111");
       $p->setData("name","real val name");
       $p->setData("custom_attr","real val");
       $p->save();
```

I created a `custom_attr` attribute via the admin panel and the above code is giving an error.

> There has been an error processing your request

The error is:

> a:5:{i:0;s:476:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`magento_oguz`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set`
>   (`attribute_set_id`) ), query was: INSERT INTO
>   `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_type_id`, `sku`, `created_at`,
>   `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, '2015-10-06 20:34:57', '2015-10-06
>   20:34:57')";i:1;s:1940:"#0

Why am I getting this error? How can I save a value for this attribute?

Comment: I made some copy edits and formatting changes in the hope of helping you have a better chance to get a good answer here. (Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way.)

Comment: is your new attribute assigned to an attribute set ?

Comment: Assigned to default attribute set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to come from you custom attribute.

When you execute that piece of code you basically create a new product.
And Magento requires an attribute_set_id when you create a product.

This piece of code down here will probably execute without error :

```
$p = Mage::getModel("catalog/product");
$p->setData("sku","real val sku111");
$p->setData("name","real val name");
$p->setData("custom_attr","real val");
// Assuming "Default" attribute set id is 9
$p->setAttributeSetId(9);
$p->save();
```

If you want to edit an existing product you will have to load id prior to any setData calls using something such as :

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku','real val sku111');
```